# socket.io's "Get Started: Chat application" tutorial simply does not run

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I just followed socket.io's ["Get started: Chat application"](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) tutorial step by step until integrating the socket.io.
But when integrating socket.io nothing happens!?
I simply don't see a "a user connected" message in the console after reloading the page!
I assume the problem is on the client side, but I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: Did you go step by step? Did you verify the code? Any errors? Could you post the link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is here: 
 https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

As i posted somewhere else, there seems to be a little bug (or missing detail) in the clients html file!? 
After days of trying and looking at other tutorials i changed this:
var socket = io.connect();
to this:
var socket = io.connect('http://local.host:port');
and this does the job now!